# How to make sure that a chat-room was left successfully? (instance.connection.muc.leave())

Tags: websocket, xmpp, multiuserchat, strophe.js

Here I've found that there's an ability to add a callback as the 3rd argument to a `leave` method: https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/blob/96da306f5394b901e190a3f7365fbbb676fddb51/muc/strophe.muc.js#L117

But it doesn't work.
How to add a callback or something else to a **instance.connection.muc.leave()** method to make sure that a chat-room was left successfully?
Maybe there are some more ways to make sure that we have left a chat-room?

```
function handler_cb() {
  console.log('>>>>>>>>> leave was successfull');
}
function leaveChat() {
  instance.connection.muc.leave(room, nick, handler_cb);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in the plugin itself

They use **presenceid** (stanza id) attribute to match a response from server  https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/muc/strophe.muc.js#L146

but not all the servers use stanza id in presences. Actually there is nothing about presence ID in [XEP-0045](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#exit) exit presence, so some servers may implement an ID echo logic but mostly not (and looks like your XMPP server as well)

So I recommend to set this header by yourself, w/o 'presenceid':

```
function leaveChat() {
  instance.connection.addHandler(leaveCallback, null, "presence", "unavailable");
  instance.connection.muc.leave(room, nick);
}

function leaveCallback() {
  console.log('>>>>>>>>> leave was successfull');
  instance.connection.deleteHandler(leaveCallback);
}
```